# How to match the two same id and import the required ids

Tags: string, perl

I need to match the two same ids like `rid="Vajravelu:1978"` and `matchid="Vajravelu:1978"`.

The perl programme working below mentioned logic

Step 1 
First mathcing the two same id `rid="Vajravelu:1978"` and `matchid="Vajravelu:1978"`

Step 2
If the two ids are same matchid="Vajravelu:1978 corresponding reference id like `id="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_001"` to be stored in one variable.

Step 3
This Stored reference id varible should be written in rid='j_zna-2014-0260_ref_001'

Step 4
Finally the match id should be removed

My Input html File:

```
<p>The sample ID [[<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="Vajravelu:1978">1</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="Adesanya:2014">2</xref>]]</p>

    <ref id="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_001"><label><matchid="Vajravelu:1978">[1]</label><mixed-citation><fnm>K.</fnm> <snm>Vajravelu</snm> and <fnm>K. S.</fnm> Sastri, J. Fluid Mech. <volume><bold>86</bold></volume>, 365 (1978).</mixed-citation></ref>
    <ref id="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_002"><label><matchid="Narain:1982">[2]</label><mixed-citation>A. Narain and D. D. Joseph, Rheol. Acta. <bold>21</bold>, 228 (1982).</mixed-citation></ref>
```

My Required output xml file:

```
<p>The sample ID [[<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_001">1</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_002">2</xref>]]</p>

<ref id="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_001"><label>[1]</label><mixed-citation><fnm>K.</fnm> <snm>Vajravelu</snm> and <fnm>K. S.</fnm> Sastri, J. Fluid Mech. <volume><bold>86</bold></volume>, 365 (1978).</mixed-citation></ref>
<ref id="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_002"><label>[2]</label><mixed-citation>A. Narain and D. D. Joseph, Rheol. Acta. <bold>21</bold>, 228 (1982).</mixed-citation></ref>
```

I am beginner of the perl programming. I will try this below mentioned code. But this code is not working. Please advice

```
  #!C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open(IN,"$ARGV[0]\.html")||die("Input LaTeX filename without .html extension\n");
local $/;
my $TeX2html=<IN>;
my ($rid) = $TeX2html =~ m/rid="(.*?)"/;
my ($matchid) = $TeX2html =~ m/matchid="(.*?)"/;

while($rid = $matchid) {
                       $TeX2html =~ s/ref id="(.*?)/rid=$1/si;
                       }
print $TeX2html;
close(IN);
```

I am using the command to execute the above mentioned program `stack.pl sample >out.xml`

Comment: First - `use strict;` `use warnings;` should be the first line of your program.  Your "shebang" line is wrong - but this doesn't matter, because it's Windows. (You should be supplying the path to the interpreter, e.g. `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl`)

Answer (score 4):

- `use strict;` `use warnings;` should be the first lines of your program.
- Your "shebang" line is wrong - but this doesn't matter, because it's Windows. (You should be supplying the path to the interpreter, e.g. `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl`)
- Why are you setting `$/` to `chr(26)`? If you're reading the whole file, either use `File::Slurp` or `local $/;` which will set it to `undef`.
- This doesn't do anything:

  ```
  $rid = rid="(.*?)";
  $matchid = matchid="(.*?)";
  ```

`strict` and `warnings` would tell you this.

If you're trying to regex match your content, you need `m/$regex/` if you're working with `$_` (inside a while loop) or specify what you're operating on:

```
my ($rid) = $TeX2html =~ m/rid="(.*?)"/;
my ($matchid) = $TeX2html =~ m/matchid="(.*?)"/;
```

- `while($rid = $matchid) {` isn't a conditional, it's an assignment. You probably mean `==` for numeric, and `eq` for string based. It'll be infinite looping though, as a result. (`strict` and `warnings` would tell you this too)
- `if( $rid =~ s/ref id="(.*?)"/rid=$1/ig ) {` - is nonsense, because `$rid` is something else entirely.  You're capturing the text `Vajravelu:1978` in the first regex (in both). So your `s`earch and replace pattern ... isn't going to match *anything* on the left hand side, so is never going to replace anything, so is going to infinite loop. (Even with the right sort of `while` conditional).

Maybe you meant to change `$TeX2html` rather than `$rid`? (not entirely sure though, because now I'm getting lost with what you're trying to do.

Edit: What I have so far for reference:

```
#!c:\Strawberry\perl\bin
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/;
my $TeX2html=<DATA>;

my ($rid) = $TeX2html =~ m/rid="(.*?)"/;
my ($matchid) = $TeX2html =~ m/matchid="(.*?)"/;

print $rid;
print $matchid;

#sorry - no idea what this is trying to do.
#if ($rid eq $matchid) {
#        if( $rid =~ s/ref id="(.*?)"/rid=$1/ig ) {
#                  print "$rid";
#        }
# }

print $TeX2html;


__DATA__
<p>The sample ID [[<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="Vajravelu:1978">1</xref>, <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="Adesanya:2014">2</xref>]]</p>

    <ref id="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_001"><label><matchid="Vajravelu:1978">[1]</label><mixed-citation><fnm>K.</fnm> <snm>Vajravelu</snm> and <fnm>K. S.</fnm> Sastri, J. Fluid Mech. <volume><bold>86</bold></volume>, 365 (1978).</mixed-citation></ref>
    <ref id="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_002"><label><matchid="Narain:1982">[2]</label><mixed-citation>A. Narain and D. D. Joseph, Rheol. Acta. <bold>21</bold>, 228 (1982).</mixed-citation></ref>
```

But really - I don't understand that `while` loop logic, so I can't really help.

Comment: I am using perl program  to clean the file in post process stage. I am getting the output html to xml through the perl program. My input file is not maintained unique id. But the xml output wants to maintain the unique ids. My requirement is ref id = " " should be replaced rid=" " .  I will try to match the text and reference part $rid and $matchid variable. This two ids is matched $rid, $matchid the corresponding ref id=" " should be replaced on the rid=" ". I don't know how get this output

Comment: What are you using to do the XML?

Comment: I follow your instruction but how to execute the while loop. The program is not compile. I edit and save my question

Comment: I am using LaTeX to convert tex to html document. Using perl html to xml process.

Comment: Yes. It won't compile when there are errors in it - that's the point of `strict` and `warnings` - they refuse to let you run shoddy code. Which is good. If annoying. Converting from HTML to XML is potentially difficult. Can you output directly as XML from LaTeX? Also - your code update - you've still got that `while` loop, which is broken, because it's `=` not `eq`.

Comment: I can't understand the strict and warnings concepts. This is more sticky to understand. If it is possible to provide a sample program. That is helpful for me

Comment: I can't, because I can't understand your program logic. That `while` loop simply doesn't make sense. However I have edited something so far:

Comment: Two ids are same like rid and matchid.   First i match this two id for your ideas like `my ($rid) = $TeX2html =~ m/rid="(.*?)"/;
my ($matchid) = $TeX2html =~ m/matchid="(.*?)"/;`. I am struggle to pick the `ref id=" "` and past the corresponding `rid=" "`

Comment: If you not understand what i say?. Please check and compare the **input html**  and in my required **output xml**  code in my question. Please advice what i do to get the required output.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to. What you're trying to do in that `while` loop is considerably more complicated than it looks, and I'm not prepared to try and figure out an algorithm for you. Not when your starting point is code that simply doesn't work in the first place.