# How to declare string compare infinite loop?

Tags: perl

I am compare the two strings like `(textid, citeid)`.

If the two ids `(textid, citeid)` are equal the corresponding `uniqueid` should be replaced in `textid` in throughout the **Text Citation Part**.

MWE:

```
#!C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
open(IN,"$ARGV[0]\.html")||die("Input LaTeX filename without .html extension\n");
local $/;
my $String_Match=<IN>;

my ($textid) = $String_Match =~ m/textid="(.*?)"/;
my ($citeid) = $String_Match =~ m/citeid="(.*?)"/;
my ($uniqueid) = $String_Match =~ m/ref uniqueid="(.*?)"/;

if ($textid eq $citeid)
{
        if ($String_Match=~m/textid="(.*?)"/s)
                {
                $String_Match =~ s/textid="(.*?)"/textid="$uniqueid"/si;
                }
}

print $String_Match;
```

The string compare `eq` function is not working for infinite loop like (while or do-while)

The above MWE execute the condition only one time. But my required output `textid` should be replaced `uniqueid` throughout the file.

**My Input File:**

```
 Text Citation Part
    <xref textid="Narain:1982">1</xref>
    <xref textid="Nasir:2012">2</xref>
    <xref textid="Yao:2011">3</xref>
    <xref textid="Cogley:1968">4</xref>

    Reference Citation Part
    <ref uniqueid="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_001"><citeid="Narain:1982"></ref>
    <ref uniqueid="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_002"><citeid="Nasir:2012"></ref>
    <ref uniqueid="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_003"><citeid="Yao:2011"></ref>
    <ref uniqueid="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_004"><citeid="Cogley:1968"></ref>
```

My Required Output File: >out.txt

```
Text Citation Part
<xref textid="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_001">1</xref>
<xref textid="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_002">2</xref>
<xref textid="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_003">3</xref>
<xref textid="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_004">4</xref>

Reference Citation Part
<ref uniqueid="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_001"><citeid="Narain:1982"></ref>
<ref uniqueid="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_002"><citeid="Nasir:2012"></ref>
<ref uniqueid="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_003"><citeid="Yao:2011"></ref>
<ref uniqueid="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_004"><citeid="Cogley:1968"></ref>
```

Please advice how to execute the logic.....

Comment: Is the whitespace difference in input and output on purpose?

Comment: @simbabque I can't understand. What are you saying?

Comment: I would go through the file line by line, store numbers in hash with textid as key, then store all the unique ids there too, then build your output from that. You can of course also slurp as you are doing, then grab all textids into array and so forth, but I would find line by line simpler.

Comment: The indentation is different.

Comment: @bytepusher If it is possible to provide the MWE is easy to understand the logic.

Comment: I know it would be nice to get someone to do it for you, but Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service. We'll help you with problems you're having in your code.

Comment: Please ignore the indentation. I will make a mistake past the content.

Comment: @Sobrique Ok fine. I understand. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The string compare eq function is not working for infinite loop like (while or do-while)

It wouldn't. You're not actually changing the values of `$textid` or `$citeid` within your loop, so your condition is *always* true.

I assume you're having a similar problem to your previous question: [How to match the two same id and import the required ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213162/how-to-match-the-two-same-id-and-import-the-required-ids)

But the problem remains the same. A `while` loop continues to execute until the condition it's testing is no longer satisfied.

Because you don't change `$textid` or `$citeid` within your loop, you're just applying the same text transform over and over to `$String_Match` (maybe. If it never matches in the first place, the transform isn't even applied, you just go around in circles doing nothing at all.

In fact, it's rather hard to say in the first place what you're intending your `while` (or `if`) loop to *actually do* in the first place.

What it may be useful to know, is that perl has `hash`es. You can read about them in [`perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) - they let you associate a keys and values.

Like, for example:

```
my $input_text = '<ref uniqueid="j_zna-2014-0260_ref_001"><citeid="Narain:1982"></ref>';

my ( $cite_id ) = $input_text =~ m/citeid="(.*?)"/;
my ( $unique_id ) = $input_text =~ m/uniqueid="(.*?)"/;

my %unique_id_for;
$unique_id_for{$cite_id} = $unique_id;
```

This will construct you a hash associating 'cite IDs' and 'unique ids' from your reference list.

```
'Narain:1982' => 'j_zna-2014-0260_ref_001'
```

Which you can then use in the rest of your script as part of a search and replace.